# Java list! How do I get an object to determine if there is another object

Tags: greenfoot

```
// test for rock
        List rocks = getWorld().getObjectsAt(x , y, Rock.class);

        /* Look up the List class (java.util.List) in the Java API
         * and determine what method to use with the 'rocks' List
         * to determine if there was a rock. Put the correct test
         * in the 'if()' statement below.
         */

        if () {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
```

Have to fill in the "if()" statement above return true;
Really confused how to get the if statement with lst. 
Please help! and send knowledge of how to do! Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to check if a concrete object Rock is on the list 'rocks'. Then you just have to use the method "contains". public boolean List.contains(Object o) checks if the object 'o' exists on the list.

```
Rock myRock = //whatever sentence you use to create the rock you're checking

if (rocks.contains(myRock) {
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Comment: If that is the case, he could skip the if statement altogether by returning the ' `rocks.contains(myRock);`

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
if (!rocks.isEmpty()) { //is true if your list with rocks is not empty
    return true;
}
```